# grab +1 data from same page as code

Tags: php, screen-scraping

Is there any coding method to grab +1 data off of the current website? Example, I know there is no API yet for Google's +1 but is there a way to search for the string posting the data on the same page as the php?

Search for aggregateCount and go to next `>x<` and pull between those and set it as a variable?

I've seen the button posted in a few different ways:

```
<span id="aggregateCount" class="a-Ec-e-fl-Ut-wf">37.6k</span>
<div id="aggregateCount" class="YJ">2</div>
```

Google's javascript posts the number of +1's but it's after code runs so I don't know if PHP can grab it that late in processes. Any other way?

Answer (score 0):

There's indeed no API I know of, but you can request `https://plusone.google.com/u/0/_/+1/fastbutton?url=yoururlencodedpage`, and look for the `window.__SSR = {'c':  1.0 ,'is': 0};` string. The `c` value is the count (as a float for some reason...). Prone to absolute breakage if Google decides to change it in the slightest. If you personnaly liked the page (and are logged in by your code for some weird reason) there's more data in `window.__SSR`.